# Compute the fermion number density

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, density

Consider fermion DM with g internal degrees of freedom and the statistical distribution results in:

$$f(E) = \frac{g}{ \exp[(E − µ)/T] + 1}$$

with $g = 1$ when $E < µ$
and $g = 0$ when $E > µ$

When I integrate $f(E)$ the phase-space, in the relativistic limit, distribution I get this:

$n = \frac{gT^3}{2\pi^2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(e^x +1)} dx =\frac{3 \zeta(3)gT^3}{4\pi^2}$ (1)

But the answer I'm looking for is

$n  = \frac{g  m^3  v^3}{6\pi^2}$ (2)

where $v$ is the fermi velocity  $v = \sqrt{2E_f/m}$

I don't see how to get from (1) to (2), what am I missing? I'm sure it must be something dumb..

Comment: Yes, I mean zeta, thanks

Comment: Have you computed $E_f$ and thus $v$ as a function of $T$?

Comment: I get $n = \frac{m^3 v^3}{3 \pi^2}$ when computing $\E_f $ and then computing $\v^3$ and then clear n.

Comment: I think your condition for $g$ is only true at $T=0$.

Comment: You seem to have forgotton $\mu$ in your integral. It will shift the limits of integration Also why is $g$ determined by $\mu$?  This is not the usual case.

Comment: The conditions for g were given in the exercise

Comment: I checked the integral in textbooks and it seems fine. But I see that my substitution for $E_f$ is not correct because I use the form for non-relativistic system, however when I use the one for relativistic systems which is: $E_f = \pi (\frac{3n}{\pi})^\frac{1}{3} $ I still get the answer wrong.

Comment: I got it, used the fermi momentum to get the fermi energy, to then get the fermi velocity and cleared n. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Is $E_f$ the Fermi energy? The why the integral is to infinity? and why finite temperature?